# How do I handle my pagination in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, pagination, components, jsx

Below is my code to handle pagination and add prev and next buttons to my site.

```
const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(props.match.params.pageno);

useEffect(() => {setPageNumber(props.match.params.pageno)},[props]);

useEffect(() => {
    
        async function fetchData() {
            try {
                const { data } = await axios.get('http://api.tvmaze.com/shows?page=' +pageNumber);
                setShowsData(data);
                setLoading(false);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
        
        fetchData();
    }, [ pageNumber ]);

return (
            <div>
                    <Link className={pageNumber===0 ? 'hidden' : 'showlink'} to={`/shows/page/${parseInt(pageNumber)-1}`}>
                        Previous
                    </Link>
                    <Link className='showlink' to={`/shows/page/${parseInt(pageNumber)+1}`}>
                        Next
                    </Link>
            </div>
        );
```

App.css:

```
.hidden{
   display:none;
}
```

How can I get this done?

I am trying to hide the Previous link when the page number is 0 as there is nothing before that. I tried the above code but it had no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also do condition rendering for `pageNumber` like,

```
{ pageNumber !== 0 && <Link>{your code}</Link> }
```

For this condition also you've to check the type of your datatype like `string` is coming in `pageNumber` and you're comparing with `int` then this code does not have any effect.

Using this conditional rendering you don't have to rely on the CSS part this will to conditional rendering which is handled by javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a type mismatch between `pageNumber` and 0.  You solve for this in your next `Link` by calling `parseInt(pageNumber)`.  You need to do this for your className check as well.  Otherwise you will never meet that condition you're checking for.

Quick refresher:

```
"0" === 0 // false
"0" == 0 // true
```

Triple equals always checks for the data type while double equals will attempt to perform [type coercion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_coercion) on the right side value.